# getting number of hours until the next event

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I've got a table with this data:

```
[ID]  [event_name]  [last_event]
 1     stats         2011-01-01 01:47:32
```

`last_event` is a timestamp. The event occurs every 48 hours (it's a cron job). I'd like to show my users the number of hours until the event executes again.

So far I've got:

```
SELECT (lastFinish + INTERVAL 48 HOUR) FROM `cron_status`
```

which gives me the exact time and date of the next occurence: `2011-01-03 01:47:32`. So I figured if I subtracted the current datetime...

```
SELECT ((lastFinish + INTERVAL 48 HOUR) - SYSDATE()) FROM `cron_status`
```

which (I think?) gives me the difference in unix time: `1980015`. But if I divide that by `3600` to convert the seconds to hours...

```
SELECT (((lastFinish + INTERVAL 48 HOUR) - SYSDATE())/3600) FROM `cron_status`
```

I get numbers an order of magnitude too high: `549.99`.

Where am I going wrong? The target is returning the number of hours until the next execution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result can be obtained directly, using the `timediff()` MySQL function:

```
  SELECT timediff(lastFinish + INTERVAL 48 HOUR, now()) FROM cron_status;
```

should display the time as `hh:mm:ss`. Assuming `lastFinish` is a `datetime`.

In order to get the answer in hours instead,

```
  SELECT timestampdiff(HOUR, now(), lastFinish + INTERVAL 48 HOUR) FROM cron_status;
```

Note that `timediff` does `arg1 - arg2` while `timestampdiff` does `arg2 - arg1`.